# if i add 2 numbers in an array and push to a new array, how to i find those 2 numbers from the value in the second array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to be able to get the 2 values from the `cutArray` that create the new value in `lengthInputs`. Here is my code so far:

```
function calculate() {
  let cutArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".cutLength").values()); //gets all input box values as string
  let quantityArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".quantity").values());
  let lengthInputs = [];

  //loops through input values and adds each individual index together as an integer then returns it to lengthInputs array
  for (i = 0; i < cutArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(cutArray[i].value);
    for (k = 0; k < cutArray.length; k++) {
      lengthInputs.push(parseInt(cutArray[i].value) + parseInt(cutArray[k].value));
      console.log(cutArray[k].value + "k");
    }
  }
```

Comment: please add some data instead of a query selector to something which is not included.

Comment: Can you explain why your example includes `quantityArray` when it is not used? Maybe you wanted to loop over it in the `k` loop instead of `cutArray`?

Comment: ignore quantityArray for now, its not in use. As for the querySelector all it does is get input fields from the html file. like this: <input class="cutLength" placeholder="Cut length(mm)">. there are 3 with the same class in the html file

Answer (score 0):

You could make your `lengthInputs` contain objects with `first`, `second` and `sum` properties where `first` and `second` are objects with `index` (index in `cutArray`) and `value` (`cutArray[index]`) and `sum` being the sum of two values:

```js
function calculate() {
  const cutArray = Array.from({length: 10}, (_) => Math.random() * 100)
  const quantityArray = Array.from({length: 10}, (_) => Math.random() * 100)
  const lengthInputs = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < cutArray.length; i++) {
    for (let k = 0; k < cutArray.length; k++) {
      lengthInputs.push({
        first: { index: i, value: cutArray[i] },
        second: { index: k, value: cutArray[k] },
        sum: cutArray[i] + cutArray[k]
      });
    }
  }

  return lengthInputs;
}

console.log(calculate())
```

You could also make `first` and `second` be just specific values if you don't need their indexes.
https://jsfiddle.net/q8gtdhws/5/

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)